# Can I change my review of a question?

Tags: discussion

I was going through the review queue on questions flagged to be closed, and after taking a good amount of time considering a question and agreeing it should be closed, I hit Leave Open by mistake. Is there any way I can go back to fix my vote? I know that additional close votes will be along in due time so the specific question is not of importance.

Comment: You can use the back button to get back to the question, and then go directly to the question to leave your close-vote. I don't think there's any better way atm.

Comment: @Deduplicator what if the review was for an Edit? I think edit reviews (approve/reject) should be possible to modify, or at least, undo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find the review:

- You can check [your review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/own/history).
- You can also get there from the appropriate review queue, choosing the "history" tab, scrolling to the bottom and checking the "Show only my own reviews (including skipped)" checkbox.
- You could also use your browser's history.

You cannot actually change your review, but you can still "fix" it by taking the appropriate action on the post itself (voting to close in your case).

Comment: link is broken. can we still not change our review mistake? i would like to give credit to the original editor.